# splitting sheets into workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to split my worksheets into separate workbooks but "run-time error 1004, method saveas of object _workbook failed" is poping up. How to fix it? I use the code below and it works perfectly on my Windows laptop, but not on my Mac.

```
Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So have you thought that the file path may work differently on a Mac?

Comment: yes, because it worked perfectly on windows, actually it worked on my mac as well before i don't know what i miss now

Comment: well, this is an open statement from one of my mmacros written to work on my macs:    Workbooks.Open ("/Users/Final_V1/" & rCell.Value & ".xlsx"). Notice anything?